# MS Access: How can I create a union with these 2 queries and get an overall count?

Tags: ms-access, union

I have 2 tables in a database, basically current sales (dbo_SalesItem) and historical sales (dbo_SalesItemHistory). I have a query to get the count of unique vendor names from each table, but how can I join these together to get a single total from both queries?

The fields in the tables are identical.

```
SELECT dbo_SalesItem.Vendor AS [Vendor ID], dbo_Vendor.Vendor_Name AS [Vendor Name], Count(*) AS [Count]
FROM (dbo_SalesDoc INNER JOIN dbo_SalesItem ON dbo_SalesDoc.Sales_Doc_Num = dbo_SalesItem.Sales_Doc_Num) INNER JOIN dbo_Vendor ON dbo_SalesItem.Vendor = dbo_Vendor.Vendor_ID
WHERE (((dbo_SalesDoc.Hold_Code)="ITEMLINK" Or (dbo_SalesDoc.Hold_Code)="TKTLINK") AND ((dbo_SalesDoc.Sales_Doc_Num) Like "ORD*"))
GROUP BY dbo_SalesItem.Vendor, dbo_Vendor.Vendor_Name, dbo_SalesDoc.Last_Update_On
HAVING (((dbo_SalesDoc.Last_Update_On)>=DateAdd("d",-90,Date())))
ORDER BY Count(*) DESC;

SELECT dbo_SalesItemHistory.Vendor AS [Vendor ID], dbo_Vendor.Vendor_Name AS [Vendor Name], Count(*) AS [Count]
FROM (dbo_SalesDoc INNER JOIN dbo_SalesItemHistory ON dbo_SalesDoc.Sales_Doc_Num = dbo_SalesItemHistory.Sales_Doc_Num) INNER JOIN dbo_Vendor ON dbo_SalesItemHistory.Vendor = dbo_Vendor.Vendor_ID
WHERE (((dbo_SalesDoc.Hold_Code)="ITEMLINK" Or (dbo_SalesDoc.Hold_Code)="TKTLINK") AND ((dbo_SalesDoc.Sales_Doc_Num) Like "ORD*"))
GROUP BY dbo_SalesItemHistory.Vendor, dbo_Vendor.Vendor_Name, dbo_SalesDoc.Last_Update_On
HAVING (((dbo_SalesDoc.Last_Update_On)>=DateAdd("d",-90,Date())))
ORDER BY Count(*) DESC;
```

The results from the queries look like this:

```
Vendor ID    Vendor Name    Count
12345        Big Vendor     1200
23453        Big Vendor      900
43498        Other Vendor    600
98342        This Vendor     500
08943        Small Vendor    100
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery to `UNION ALL` your 2 existing queries.  Discard their `ORDER BY` clauses, though.  Then the parent query can be a `GROUP BY` which totals the counts for each vendor.

```sql
SELECT
    sub.[Vendor ID],
    sub.[Vendor Name],
    Sum(sub.Count) As SumOfCount
FROM
    (
        SELECT dbo_SalesItem.Vendor AS [Vendor ID], dbo_Vendor.Vendor_Name AS [Vendor Name], Count(*) AS [Count]
        FROM (dbo_SalesDoc INNER JOIN dbo_SalesItem ON dbo_SalesDoc.Sales_Doc_Num = dbo_SalesItem.Sales_Doc_Num) INNER JOIN dbo_Vendor ON dbo_SalesItem.Vendor = dbo_Vendor.Vendor_ID
        WHERE (((dbo_SalesDoc.Hold_Code)="ITEMLINK" Or (dbo_SalesDoc.Hold_Code)="TKTLINK") AND ((dbo_SalesDoc.Sales_Doc_Num) Like "ORD*"))
        GROUP BY dbo_SalesItem.Vendor, dbo_Vendor.Vendor_Name, dbo_SalesDoc.Last_Update_On
        HAVING (((dbo_SalesDoc.Last_Update_On)>=DateAdd("d",-90,Date())))
        UNION ALL
        SELECT dbo_SalesItemHistory.Vendor AS [Vendor ID], dbo_Vendor.Vendor_Name AS [Vendor Name], Count(*) AS [Count]
        FROM (dbo_SalesDoc INNER JOIN dbo_SalesItemHistory ON dbo_SalesDoc.Sales_Doc_Num = dbo_SalesItemHistory.Sales_Doc_Num) INNER JOIN dbo_Vendor ON dbo_SalesItemHistory.Vendor = dbo_Vendor.Vendor_ID
        WHERE (((dbo_SalesDoc.Hold_Code)="ITEMLINK" Or (dbo_SalesDoc.Hold_Code)="TKTLINK") AND ((dbo_SalesDoc.Sales_Doc_Num) Like "ORD*"))
        GROUP BY dbo_SalesItemHistory.Vendor, dbo_Vendor.Vendor_Name, dbo_SalesDoc.Last_Update_On
        HAVING (((dbo_SalesDoc.Last_Update_On)>=DateAdd("d",-90,Date())))
    ) AS sub
GROUP BY
    sub.[Vendor ID],
    sub.[Vendor Name]
ORDER BY 3 DESC;
```